# Объясните в чем смысл сервиса stdlib/com

Tags: javascript

Это вроде веб-компонентов ? как он работает, что за принцип, я у себя пишу компоненты или они на сервере ?

> The Function as a Service Software Library
>   Build, Share and Scale Microservices —
>   Without Managing Servers

Answer (score 1):

Прочитай [это](https://habrahabr.ru/post/249183/)

Если коротко, то архитектурный стиль ***микросервисов*** — это подход, при котором единое приложение строится как набор небольших сервисов, каждый из которых работает в собственном процессе и коммуницирует с остальными используя легковесные механизмы, как правило HTTP. Эти сервисы построены вокруг бизнес-потребностей и развертываются независимо с использованием полностью автоматизированной среды. Существует абсолютный минимум централизованного управления этими сервисами. Сами по себе эти сервисы могут быть написаны на разных языках и использовать разные технологии хранения данных.

**Update:**

```
// Пример hello world микросервис 
// Сервис будет реагировать на HTTP запрос
module['exports'] = function helloWorld (hook) {
  // хукаем рекуест Node.js http.IncomingMessage
  var host = hook.req.host;

  hook.res.end(host + ' says, "Hello world!"');
};
```

[Тут подробный пример с использованием stdlib](http://thisdavej.com/creating-node-js-microservices-with-ease-using-stdlib/)

Comment: а есть пример ?, я имею ввиду как можно сделать просто приложение `привет мир`